# Transportation from Bangoan to Kolkata Airport

Tags: india, airport-transfer, taxis, bangladesh, ccu

I'll be travelling from Bangladesh. Expected time to reach Benapole at 8am. I will be in a bit of a hurry to catch my flight at 5pm.

Is there any taxi service from Benapole/Bangoan to Kolkata Airport?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be nice to have something more up to date than 2008 and a little more promising than "there may be" but [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Benapole) does at least mention:

> On the Indian side the bus stop is near the immigration office. As you step out of the immigration office to the official moneychangers stalls, there may be people sitting around who can arrange a taxi to Kolkata. I paid Rs 900 in Jan 2008, but usually it will be more.

I am rather relying on my experience of India that wherever there is one taxi there have been hundreds if not thousands. And though the report is vintage by web standards the likelihood is that facilities have improved rather than deteriorated since.

Google Earth lists two ranks:  Mondalpara Auto Stand Bat Tala, Dua Para Rd. and Pratapgarh Autostand, SH 1.